# How do I make a subfolder act like a document root using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

Site location: http://localhost/~username/website

The website loads lots of images with an absolute url such as /image/image.png.

I need that request to go to:
http://localhost/~username/website/image/image.png 
instead of 
http://localhost/image/image.png.

I also need this to not affect any other folders or the root folder. So that I could also access http://localhost/image/image.png if I wanted to.

Is there some way of making it so that when it's requested from this subfolder to redirect?

I want the absolute reference like /css/something.css and /image/image.png to points to /subdirectory/css/something.css and /subdirectory/image/image.png. That way I don't have to rewrite all the absolute references. So, I don't want to modify the root directory.

I'm wondering if setting up a virtual host that would not allow the subdirectory "website" to have no ability to access the root. I don't ever need root access from this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are allowed to use .htaccess file in your webserver. Look at this how to enable in apache:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file

Create a .htaccess file in root or *~username/website* directory  Then write this to your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^~username/web/image/(.*) /image/$1
```

Comment: I'd like it to work for all references. I do /image/image.png and /css/style.css and I don't want them to hit / but /~username/project/ instead.

Comment: Then add another rule like this: `RewriteRule ^~username/web/css/(.*) /css/$1`

Comment: Would this go in my subdirectory or the root?

Answer (score 0):

Why the requirement to use `/image/image.png`? Why wouldn't you just use one of these instead:

```
http://localhost/~username/website/image/image.png (absolute)
image/image.png (relative without preceding slash)
```

Comment: The site is already built and has lots of these. I don't want to modify a working website. This is a localhost clone

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess OR in Apache/vhost config:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ~username/website/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'd like it to work anytime there is a absolute reference within this subfolder to add /~username/subfolder to it. So /include/style.css would point to /~username/subfolder/include/style.css. However, it wouldn't affect the root domain so I could have a /include/style.css also.

Comment: Can you remove the filetype dependency?

Comment: I'd like to not have this in the root because I'd like to have several "websites" that each act independently. Is it possible to write something in the subfolder htaccess?

Comment: To make this rule work, you must have it in root .htaccess or in Apache config. Otherwise you will have have to create multiple .htaccess in `images, css, is` etc directories

Comment: Is it possible to setup the VirtualHost so that /subdirectory acts fully independent from the root? So that /image would go to /subdirectory/image?

Comment: Yes you can setup `VirtualHost` by setting `subdirectory` as `DocumentRoot`