# How do I make a subfolder act like a document root by htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Sub site location: http://t.test.com/cooking/index.php

Main site location: http://t.test.com/index.php

The subsite loads lots of images with an absolute url such as `/_upload/images/image.png` so the site lost picture links.

I need `/_upload/images/image.png` to go to

http://t.test.com/cooking/_upload/images/image.png instead of http://t.test.com/_upload/images/image.png.

I also need this to not affect any other folders or the root folder. So that I could also access http://t.test.com/_upload/images/image.png if I wanted to.

I have tried the solutions in this article but none of them work.
[How do I make a subfolder act like a document root using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782032/how-do-i-make-a-subfolder-act-like-a-document-root-using-htaccess)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cooking/$1 [L]
```

either

```
RewriteRule ^cooking/(.*) /$1
```

Is there some way of making it so that when it's requested from this subfolder to redirect?

my .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule rewrite_module>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(css|includes|cache|js|siteadmin|images|_upload|mail|timthumb.php|scripts|styles|ajax_post.php|mail)($|/)  - [L]
    #RewriteCond $1 !^(css|includes|cache|js|siteadmin|images|_upload|mail|timthumb.php|scripts|styles) - [L]

    # Apache 2.4
    <IfModule authz_core_module>

        # Remove the extension
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.php$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
        RewriteRule .* %1 [QSA,R,L]

#----- Rewrite subfolder route-----
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cooking/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^cooking/(.*) /$1

        # Point to the file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /[\w\-]+$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)$
        RewriteRule .* %1.php [QSA,END]

    </IfModule>

    # Apache 2.2
    <IfModule !authz_core_module>

        # Point to the file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /[\w\-]+$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)$
        RewriteRule .* %1.php [QSA,L]

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

==========
index.php

```
$getSQL = "Select * From `foods`";

$tempData = $sql -> SelectDB($getSQL);
$thisData = FormatData($tempData['data']);

define('UPLOAD_IMG_PATH',"_upload/images/");

function FormatData( $data )
{

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        foreach($value as $list_key =>$list_value){


            // separate pictures
            if (strstr($list_key,'pic') && !strstr($list_key,'_alt')) {
                $picArr = explode(",", $list_value);
                foreach ($picArr as $pic_key => $pic_value) {
                    if(!is_file(UPLOAD_IMG_PATH."/".$pic_value)){
                        unset($picArr[$pic_key]);
                    }
                    else{
                        $picArr[$pic_key] = '/'.UPLOAD_IMG_PATH.$picArr[$pic_key];

                    }

                    if(empty($picArr)){

                        $picArr[0]='styles/images/news/noimage.jpg';

                    }

                }
                $data[$key][$list_key] = $picArr;
            }


        }
    }
    return $data;
}

$tpl->assign('thisData', $thisData);
$tpl->display('index.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^_upload/images/   cooking%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

So , you could be able to access images when the URI start with `/_upload/images/image.png` and internally get from real path `/cooking/_upload/images/image.png`

Comment: I got the result "styles/images/news/noimage.jpg".  I updated my question. function FormatData didn't find the files.